# CSS оптимизатор

Tags: оптимизация, css

Есть ли CSS оптимизаторы, которые могут пройтись по сайту и по CSS файлу и показать никогда не используемые стили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Helium CSS](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css)

Comment: Он для одной страницы, или всего сайта? Я не понял из описания.

Comment: "Helium is a tool for discovering unused CSS across many pages on a web site." Автор также рекомендует использовать на локальной версии сайта т.к. посетители будут видеть результаты его работы.

Comment: @HappyCougar, если нужно что-то по проще, то в хромовской консоли есть кнопка Audits. Там нажимаем кнопку Run и смотрим список с заголовком Remove unused CSS rules. Я так понимаю Вы хотите оптимизировать скорость загрузки страницы. Там в отчете аудита будут и другие советы по оптимизации. Рекомендую присмотреться.

Answer (score 0):

Для Фаерфокса есть плагин http://www.brothercake.com/dustmeselectors/
Посмотрите может это вам подойдет...

Answer (score 0):

Я использую плагин для FireFox [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/css-usage/). Он проверяет использование стилей для открытой в браузере страницы.